# How to enforce post encoding in tomcat 7?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

Is there a way to enforce UTF-8 encoding on POST operations for tomcat 7, regardless of what the browser may send to tomcat?

It runs with the latest JRE from http://java.sun.com/getjava

Comment: I ended up writing my own unconditional filter for that to no avail, because the application (for which I have no access to the source code) changes it back to latin1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "enforce" UTF-8 encoding on post operations, you rather have the ability to convert requests to UTF-8 by creating a servlet filter, for this check these links:

http://www.javaservletsjspweb.in/2009/05/character-encoding-filter-java-servlets.html#.U0CQ46JqSMg

http://dertompson.com/2007/01/29/encoding-filter-for-java-web-applications/

Comment: Accepting this as the correct answer because of the links that helped me debug the problem even further.